# Show item in foreach empty when repeat in Razor Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a table built in my razor and I want it when the name of an institution is repeated, made he's an empty field. Is there any way to do this?

Like this plunker:
https://plnkr.co/qitrBwCksORassfJkpss

Razor:

```html
<style>
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    th {
        background-color: #673673;
        color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    tr {
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }


    header h1 span {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<header style="text-align:center;">
    <h1>Aperam South America</h1>
    <h4>
        Relatório de Demandas por Instituições <br />
        @DateTime.Now
    </h4>
</header>
<main style="margin-top: 5%;">
    <table id="report-table">
        <tr>
            <th>Instituition</th>
            <th>Descrição da demanda</th>
            <th>Periodicidade</th>
            <th>Tempo Estimado</th>
            <th>Situação Demanda</th>
        </tr>


        @foreach (var query in Model.GroupBy(i => i.COD_IDENT_INSTI).Distinct())
        {
            foreach (var demanda in query)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@demanda.INSTITUICAO_SOCIAL.NOM_FANTA_INSTI</td>
                    <td>@demanda.DES_COMPL_DEMAN)</td>
                    <td>@demanda.PERIODICIDADE.DES_COMPL_COMPT</td>
                    <td>@demanda.VLR_TEMPO_ESTIM</td>
                    <td>@demanda.COD_SITUA_DEMAN</td>
                </tr>
            }

        }
    </table>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult GerarRelatorio(RelatorioViewModel relatorio)
    {
        switch (relatorio.Tipo)
        {
            case EnumTipoRelatorio.Nenhum:
                TempData["Message"] = new[] { Resources.relatorio_tipo_errro, "erro" };
                return RedirectToAction("Relatorios", "Relatorio");

            case EnumTipoRelatorio.demandasPorInstituicoes:
                try
                {
                    var demandas = Mapper.Map < ICollection<DEMANDA>, ICollection<DemandaViewModel>>(_demandaService.ObterTodos().ToList());
                    var instituicao = Mapper.Map<ICollection<INSTITUICAO_SOCIAL>,ICollection<InstituicaoSocialViewModel>>(_instituicaoSocialService.ObterTodos().ToList());

                    var demandasPorInstituicoes = from d in demandas join i in instituicao 
                                                  on d.COD_IDENT_INSTI equals i.COD_IDENT_INSTI
                                                  where i.DAT_CRIAC_REGIS >= relatorio.InicioFiltro &&
                                                  i.DAT_CRIAC_REGIS <= relatorio.FimFiltro
                                                  select d;



                    //return new MvcRazorToPdf.PdfActionResult("DemandasPorInstituicoes", demandasPorInstituicoes, (writer, document) => {
                    //    document.SetPageSize(PageSize.A3);
                    //});

                    return View("DemandasPorInstituicoes", demandasPorInstituicoes);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = new[] { Resources.relatorio_erro, "erro" };
                    return RedirectToAction("Relatorios", "Relatorio");
                }
        }

        //var instituicao = _instituicaoSocialService.ObterTodos().ToList();
        TempData["Message"] = new[] { Resources.relatorio_tipo_errro, "erro" };
        return RedirectToAction("Relatorios", "Relatorio");
    }
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class DemandaViewModel
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Código")]
    public int COD_IDENT_DEMAN { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Instituição")]
    public int COD_IDENT_INSTI { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Periodicidade")]
    public int COD_IDENT_PERIO { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A demanda deve possuir um nome.")]
    [MaxLength(128, ErrorMessage = "O nome da demanda deve possuir no máximo {1} caracteres.")]
    public string DES_COMPL_DEMAN { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Local da ação")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O departamento deve possuir um nome.")]
    [MaxLength(128, ErrorMessage = "O nome do departamento deve possuir no máximo {1} caracteres.")]
    public string DES_LOCAL_DEMAN { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tempo Estimado")]
    [MaxLength(64, ErrorMessage = "O nome do departamento deve possuir no máximo {1} caracteres.")]
    public string VLR_TEMPO_ESTIM { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Quantidade de voluntários")]
    public short NUM_VOLUN_DEMAN { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Custo Estimado")]
    public decimal? VLR_CUSTO_ESTIM { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Classificação")]
    public short? COD_CLASF_DEMAN { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Observação")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A demanda deve possuir uma observação.")]
    [MaxLength(1024, ErrorMessage = "A observação da demanda deve possuir no máximo {1} caracteres.")]
    public string DES_OBSER_ACAO { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Situação")]
    public short? COD_SITUA_DEMAN { get; set; }

    public virtual InstituicaoSocialViewModel INSTITUICAO_SOCIAL { get; set; }

    public virtual PeriodicidadeViewModel PERIODICIDADE { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RegistroAcaoViewModel> REGISTROACAO { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CompetenciaViewModel> COMPETENCIA { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<VoluntarioViewModel> VOLUNTARIO { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a "NoRepeat" property that can be applied to the columnn using your ui. If you don't do this in your controller then you will need to apply the logic in your view.

```
       @foreach (var query in Model.GroupBy(i => i.COD_IDENT_INSTI).Distinct())
        {
            string _InstitutionTest="";
            string _InstitutionValue="";

            foreach (var demanda in query)
            {
                if(demanda.INSTITUICAO_SOCIAL.NOM_FANTA_INSTI !=_InstitutionTest){
                   _InsitutionTest=demanda.INSTITUICAO_SOCIAL.NOM_FANTA_INSTI ;
                   _InstitutionValue=_InsitutionTest;
                }else{
                    _InstitutionValue="";
                } 

                <tr>
                    <td>@_InstitutionValue</td>
                    <td>@demanda.DES_COMPL_DEMAN)</td>
                    <td>@demanda.PERIODICIDADE.DES_COMPL_COMPT</td>
                    <td>@demanda.VLR_TEMPO_ESTIM</td>
                    <td>@demanda.COD_SITUA_DEMAN</td>
                </tr>
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you Ross! Your code really came in handy. In the future I'll fix my controller too.